# jquery's resizable plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-resizable

even though helper option is turned on, the plugin is resizing elements supplied via alsoResize option. how make it not do so?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct behavior...if you don't want to resize other elements, just leave them out of the `alsoResize` option/selector.

The `helper` option only affects the *primary* element, the ones selected with `alsoResize` are immediately resized as you go, you'd have to write your own `alsoResize` (which it itself a plugin) to have different behavior.